# Visual Studio Ctrl + F search freezes when including a '(' character

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

For some reason whenever I include the '(' character in a Ctrl + F search in Visual Studio 2013 the search bar never works. It doesn't matter what other text is included in the search bar. It doesn't matter if I choose to search on just the current document, or the entire project.

If I search on anything else that doesn't have a '(' character then Ctrl + F works just fine.

When the Ctrl + F search doesn't work I see a blue 'progress' line moving through the bottom of the search box the entire time, as if it's doing something, and I can hit the 'X' next to the search textbox to stop the search, but no matter how long I wait I never get any results back.

I haven't installed any add-on's to Visual Studio recently, so I'm not sure what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have regular expression searches on?

`(` is a meta-character for regexes and, on its own, is an invalid regex. Visual Studio is waiting for enough input for a valid regex to search with.

Comment: Oh! Looks like that's it. Thanks, I feel like an idiot for not noticing that option.